# In the Lego Batman Movie why did the writers choose the phrase "It takes a village"?

Tags: dc, batman, lego, the-lego-batman-movie

In *The Lego Batman Movie*, there seemed to be quite a few side-references to contemporary American politics, most notably Barbara Gordon saying

> "*It takes a village*"

a traditional phrase about collective effort which was famously used as the [title for Hillary Clinton's book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It_Takes_a_Village).

**Was the line inserted to to promote the producer's political views?**

Comment: Maybe you could elaborate on the other references?

Comment: Well, apparently you're not the only person who found such indications... https://www.filmcomment.com/blog/deep-focus-lego-batman-movie/

Comment: Huh? What so someone makes a common remark and we immediately draw conclusions? Not every statement is a reference to something else.

Comment: @Möoz watch the movie. Its completely out of context and must be a reference.

Comment: @TheAsh I've watched the movie, and made no such connection.

Comment: The phrase "it takes a village.." has been a proverbfar longer than Clinton or Trump. It's full form "It takes a village to raise a child", is adapted to the movie to mean "it takes a village to stop crime in Gothman, not a batman"

Comment: @CBredlow - Which is all well and good, but why then did the producers give it such prominence?

Comment: @Valorum: I guess because that’s the entire story of the movie?

Comment: @CBredlow 'Gothman' is the slightly more emo version of 'Gotham'.

Comment: '*in*famously used', perhaps. Better known as [the first half of a phrase that has it's own Wiki page titled with the first half of the phrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It_takes_a_village).